# MySQL Copiar columna de una tabla a otra

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, update

Tengo 2 tablas en PHPMyAdmin, una de ellas se llama cf, que está compeltamente vacía (0 registros), la cual tiene una columna que es ninv.

Tengo otra tabla que es ninv (que tiene 154 registros), de la cual quiero copiar los 154 registros de la columna id a la columna ninv de la tabla cf.

He probado esta sentencia, que no me da error pero no me copia ningún registro...

```
update cfvalencia
inner join ninv on cfvalencia.ninv = ninv.id
set cfvalencia.ninv=ninv.id
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a ver el fallo?

Creo que al no haber registros tengo que hacer un script PHP con un bucle que para cada registro de la tabla ninv me inserte el id de ninv en campo ninv de la tabla cf.

Pongo el código de mi intento con el script PHP y el bucle, me está copiando sólo uno:

```
<?php
include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ninv";
$result=mysql_query($consulta,$enlace);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $ninv = $row["id"];
    $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO `cfvalencia`(`ninv`) VALUES ($ninv)";
    $result=mysql_query($consulta2,$enlace);
}

   
?>
```

Y tengo el siguiente warning:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
> in

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: update, = actualiza.. insert = inserta.. si no hay registros, como que deberias insertarlos.. porque no se que estas tratando de actualizar....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lo que deseas hacer es copiar los datos de una tabla en otra (A->B), mediante un script de php, para tal efecto lo único que debes hacer es crear una copia exacta de la tabla para que no tengas problemas con los tipos de datos, hasta ahí todo correcto y por lo que veo en tu script tu lógica tampoco estaría incorrecta, el único detalle que logro ver es que estas usando la librería `mysql` la cual ya se encuentra obsoleta, debes usar `mysqli`.

El otro detalle que logré ver es que al momento de hacer la consulta estas creando una variable de consulta `result` , pero resulta que luego le cambias el valor dentro del While, por lo que en el siguiente ciclo el While se encuentra con las variables creadas anteriormente que fueron las usadas para obtener los valores de la tabla (A), debes usar otra variable. ($result2), con lo cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
include"./conectar.php";
$enlace= conectarse();

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ninv";   

$result = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $ninv = $row['id'];
        $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO `cfvalencia`(`ninv`) VALUES ($ninv)";
        $result2=mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta2);  
    }
   
?>
```

Resumiendo esto no tan solo te serviría para ingresar los id's si no también para el resto de los campos.

Answer (score 2):

Tu Update no funciona por que no hay nada que actualizar ya que tu tabla destino esta bacia, en lugar de un update tienes que hacer un insert.

**INSERT into cfvalencia(ninv)
SELECT id FROM ninv**

esto solo funcionara si ninv y id son del mismo tipo